# Selecting users whos shifts are off on 2nd day, i want to check the firstday at backend which should not be off

Tags: php, mysql

```
$first_day = $_POST['day1'];
$second_day = $_POST['day2'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_shift WHERE userid!='$_SESSION[userid]' AND grp='$user_group' AND date_start = '$second_day' AND shift='Dayoff' ORDER BY name ASC";
```

I want those users who don't have dayoff in their first day should show up. But the result i want to show is off 2nd day. Just want to check at backend that users should not have dayoff on their 1st day.

Comment: what is the format of your `date_start`?

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD 
Its working fine, i want to check the first day shift is its not dayoff then it should display the user otherwise dont.

Comment: i dont have any issue in my dates field. i want only those users 2nd days to be shown whos 1st day is not off.

Comment: Maybe with a nested query. Now as I see you select those who had the second day off. But I would suggest explaining the problem more elaborated by defining the value sets [shift: Dayoff / DayNOToff] and removing indifferent where conditions [user_id, user_group]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `subquery` where you select the id of users. Subquery is:

```
select userid from users_shift where userid!='$_SESSION[userid]' AND grp='$user_group' and date_start = '$first_day' AND shift!='Dayoff'
```

Full query is :

```
$first_day = $_POST['day1'];
$second_day = $_POST['day2'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_shift WHERE userid!='$_SESSION[userid]' AND grp='$user_group' AND date_start = '$second_day' AND shift='Dayoff' and userid in(select userid from users_shift where userid!='$_SESSION[userid]' AND grp='$user_group' and date_start = '$first_day' AND shift!='Dayoff') ORDER BY name ASC";
```

Or you can use `inner join like this`:

```
select * from users_shift s 
inner join users_shift f 
on s.userid = f.userid where 
where s.userid!='$_SESSION[userid]' AND s.grp='$user_group' And
s.date_start = '$first_day' AND s.shift!='Dayoff' And f.date_start = 
'$second_day' And f.shift = 'Dayoff';
```

P.S. query is not tested.

Comment: `select id ` which id you are talking about is it userid ?
And am getting confused that will it display the result according to 2nd day ? because 1st day is just a checkpoint if it is dayoff so i dont want their 2nd day if not then i want them.

Comment: your join suggestion looks good i will try this one and get back to you :) Thanks

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_shift WHERE userid!='$_SESSION[userid]' AND grp='$user_group' AND date_start = '$second_day' AND shift='Dayoff'AND (date_start = '$first_day' AND shift!='Dayoff') ORDER BY name ASC";
`
I was thinking about this.

Comment: yes this is also good solution. I had thought about it but never tested it. So was not sure about this solution.

Comment: Thanks for helping bro :)

Comment: Your both suggestions are working fine but i have some displaying issues in join query so i used the nested select so far its working fine, am creating different scenarios to test it. Thanks again :)